# In powershell I am trying to delete old files but not delete the template file

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell I am trying to delete old files but not delete the template file, I have the delete old files part I just don't know where to put the exclude for the template file (called NEW_paths.txt).

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-4)
$path = "C:\Somepath","C:\Somepath"
```

## Delete files older than the $limit.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force ` 
| Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } `
| Remove-Item -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an additional predicate to your where clause to exclude the file in question:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force ` 
| ? { !$_.PSIsContainer `
      -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit `
      -and $_.Name -ne "NEW_paths.txt" } `
| Remove-Item -Force
```